# Writing a type for which-Nat in pie-lang

Tags: types, racket, pie-lang

After reading [the documentation for which-Nat](https://docs.racket-lang.org/pie/#%28def._%28%28lib._pie%2Fmain..rkt%29._which-.Nat%29%29https://docs.racket-lang.org/pie/#%28part._.Types__.Constructors__and_.Eliminators%29), copied here:

```lisp
(which-Nat target base step) → X

      target : Nat
      base : X
      step : (-> Nat X)

which-Nat is a case operator on Nat.

Examples:

    > (which-Nat 0 0 (λ (smaller) smaller))

    (the Nat 0)
    > (which-Nat 17 0 (λ (smaller) smaller))

    (the Nat 16)
```

I tried to write my own clone of it, `wN`, but the following claim

```lisp
(claim wN
       (Π ((E      U        )
           (target Nat      )
           (base   E        )
           (step   (→ Nat E)))
          (→ target base step
             E)))
```

produces the error

> ```
> ; Expected U but given Nat
> ```

The fix is completely unsatisfying:

```lisp
(claim wN
       (Π ((E      U        )
           (target Nat      )
           (base   E        )
           (step   (→ Nat E)))
          (→ U U U ;target base step
             E)))
```

All three `U` are forced because if any one of `target`, `base`, and `step` are used, I get the same failure.

This is all the more surprising, because my clone of the more challenging `ind-Nat`, namely `iN`, by [a similar transcription of its documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/pie/#%28def._%28%28lib._pie%2Fmain..rkt%29._ind-.Nat%29%29), works:

```lisp
(claim iN
       (Π ((t   Nat)                    ; target
           (m   (→ Nat U))              ; motive
           (b   (m 0))                  ; base
           (s   (Π ((n-1 Nat))          ; step
                   (→ (m n-1)
                      (m (add1 n-1))))))
          (m t)))

(define iN
  (λ (t m b s)
    (ind-Nat
     t
     m
     b
     s)))

;; unit tests

(claim peas-ex
       (Π ((ℓ Nat))
          (Vec Atom ℓ)))

(define peas-ex
  (λ (ℓ)
    (iN ℓ
        mot-peas
        base-peas
        step-peas)))

(peas-ex 0)
(peas-ex 1)
(peas-ex 2)
```

What is the most specific and correct type for `which-Nat` that would let me `define` a clone the way I did for `ind-Nat`?

Answer (score 0):

I had one too many levels of abstraction. Here is a correct answer

```lisp
(claim wN
       (Π ((E      U        )
           (target Nat      )
           (base   E        )
           (step   (→ Nat E)))
          E))

(define wN
  (λ (E)
   (λ (t b s) (which-Nat t b s))))
```